# Ruby inject function

Tags: ruby

Why does the second one not return the same value as the first?

```
puts (3..5).map{|n| n**3}.inject{|sum,n| sum + n}
puts (3..5).inject{|sum,n| sum + n**3}
```

216
192

Comment: BTW, you can use `.inject(:+)` instead of `.inject{|sum,n| sum + n}`

Comment: @Stefan, better use `.inject(&:+)`.

Comment: As it will fit to more functions, i.e. if you call `.map(:name)` it will raise argument error, but if you give conversion to proc then it will work as expected. So if you use `&:+` notation then IMHO your code will look more consistent and more logical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in the first case [the starting value of the accumulator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is `27`, in the second case it is `3`.

If you use `0` as an explicit starting value, both will evaluate to the same number:

```
(3..5).map {|n| n**3 }.inject(0) {|sum,n| sum + n }
# => 216
# or just
(3..5).map {|n| n**3 }.inject(0, :+)

(3..5).inject(0) {|sum,n| sum + n**3 }
# => 216
```

Comment: please add reference to doc http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject : `If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.`

Comment: Do not use `.inject(:+)`. Instead of it use `.inject(&:+)`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier: Why? Sure, it is an unnecessary special case that probably shouldn't have been added to the API in the first place, but hey, it's there, so why not use it?

Comment: There is `for ... in` loop, why most of Rubyist don't use that? IMHO it is just convention that make all your code more readable and universal. It isn't that hard to introduce new programmer that is still learning Ruby and after showing her/him that code (s)he will try to do this with `map`.

Answer (score 5):

[`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) says:

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo is the return value for the method.
>
> ***If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.***

The below will work:

```
puts (3..5).inject(0){|sum,n| sum + n**3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following

```
1.9.3p327 :084 > (3..5).inject{|sum,n| puts sum;puts n;sum + n**3}
3
4
67
5
 => 192
```

So here final answer will be `67+125=192`

```
1.9.3p327 :085 > (3..5).map{|n| n**3}.inject{|sum,n| puts sum;puts n;sum + n}
27
64
91
125
 => 216
```

and here final answer will be `91+125=216`